# Why can't I connect my Samsung Galaxy 3 to my PC after installing the z4root app?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-apollo, usb-connection-mode

I have a problem connecting my [Samsung i5800 Galaxy 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_i5800) to a PC. First, I could connect to the PC. I had installed the [z4root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=833953) app in order to root my phone and then after installing it, I could not connect to the PC any more.

The dialog to select how to connect to the PC does not appear, though the beep sounds when I connect the phone to the USB cabel. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem in a direct way. I have restored the phone to the factory state, and it worked. And I am convinced it is because of *z4root*! I have tried the second time and the result was the same. Be careful when you root the Galaxy 3 Samsung i5800 with *z4root*.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too.  It was not related to any driver on the PC as it worked
and stopped working at some point.  The problem was on the Android phone which
for some reasons had some configuration problems.

To solve that, dial *#7284# on your phone so that it launches the PhoneUtil
application.  Then, switch to the USB -> PDA mode on the phone.  Connect the USB cable
(toggle USB -> Modem and then USB -> PDA modes if it does not work the first time)

The details are explained in:
[How to repair the USB connection problem on Android Samsung phones](http://blog.vacs.fr/index.php?post/2010/12/24/How-to-repair-the-USB-not-detected-problem-on-Android-Samsung-phones)

Comment: The solution has worked on a non-rooted Galaxy 3 as well. Thanks

Comment: After following the instructions of the linked page, I was able to use the usb debugging feature of my Galaxy S from ubuntu 10.10. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your device is **not** connected to your PC.
2. Uninstall any drivers you currently have installed for it.
3. Reboot.
4. Install the appropriate drivers from [this XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=7238660&postcount=1) (supports more than Galaxy S).
5. Install Kies from [Samsung.com's Galaxy 3 page](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/detail/supportPrdDetail.do?menu=SP01&prd_ia_cd=23020100&prd_mdl_cd=GT-I5800DKAXEU&prd_mdl_name=GT-I5800).
6. Connect your device to your PC.

This should work, but please note that when you root your phone *you do so at your own risk*.  Samsung does not support rooting.